# Ternary Operator to check more than one string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a piece of code where I am checking if the value is `null` or `turnedoff` then put a `blank space` in the variable at lefthand side. But for some reason the `turnedoff` is not getting replaced. What am I doing wrong?

JS :

```
$scope.ModelAux ={
  ssclientID: sessionStorage.clientId === ('null' || 'turnedoff') ? '' : sessionStorage.clientId
};

alert($scope.ModelAux.ssclientID);
```

CSHTML :

```
<input type="text" name="clientID" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="ModelAux.ssclientID" required/>
```

Comment: `'null'` and  `'turnedoff'` aren't booleans, so they will be converted to booleans by `||`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This

```
sessionStorage.clientId === ('null' || 'turnedoff') ?
```

should be

```
sessionStorage.clientId === 'null' || sessionStorage.clientId ===  'turnedoff' ?
```

because

```
'null' || 'turnedoff'
```

is always `'null'` and does not check if the value is `'turnedoff'`.

Comment: In addition: is `'null'` a string or do you want to check for `null`? If it's a string then `===` is OK but if its a `null` use `==` instead - this way you would catch `undefined` as well:   `null === undefined // false`
`null  == undefined // true`

Comment: the op writes `'null'` as string and checks with strict comparison. so this is a string comparison.

Comment: He does, it might not be what he is really after though

Comment: @StackExchanger, right, it could be, but `'turnedoff'` is a string an not a kind of value of javascript.

Comment: I know that only OP knows what he means

Answer (score 2):

what @Nina Scholz says is correct.  If you want to get more terse you could also do:

```
['null','turnedoff'].indexOf(sessionStorage.clientId) >= 0 ? '', sessionStorage.clientId;
```

Answer (score 1):

try following

```
(!sessionStorage.clientId || sessionStorage.clientId ===  'turnedoff') ? ''
```